# How to modify a value in list using iterator in java

Tags: java, list, iterator

```
    List firstList = new ArrayList();
    firstList.add("one");
    firstList.add("two");
    firstList.add("three");

List secondList = new ArrayList();
    secondList.add("four");
    secondList.add("five");
    secondList.add("six");

    Iterator itr = firstList.listIterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String tempString1 = (String)itr.next();
        Iterator iter = secondList.listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String trmpString2 = (String)iter.next();
            tempString1 = trmpString2;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(firstList);
```

I want to replace the first object in first list with first object in secon list..,

i.e i want out put as {four,two,three}.

How to update the firstList with secondList values using iterator??

Comment: First try to avoid *RAW* type. make it *Generic*

Comment: upvote for your try to get the output

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try this :

Use set method

```
List firstList = new ArrayList();
firstList.add("one");
firstList.add("two");
firstList.add("three");

List secondList = new ArrayList();
secondList.add("four");
secondList.add("five");
secondList.add("six");

Iterator itr = firstList.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String tempString1 = (String)itr.next();
    Iterator iter = secondList.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String trmpString2 = (String)iter.next();
         itr.set(trmpString2);    // Change the element the iterator is currently at
       // tempString1 = trmpString2;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
System.out.println(firstList);
```

Comment: There is no set method in `Iterator` interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html. You probably wanted to declare itr as `ListIterator<String>`

Comment: There is no set method in iterator.

Comment: @AlexBurdusel: you are right, we can replace by ListIterator<String> iter = lst.listIterator(); in ListIterator have method set()